# How can I make this script work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/4zuzxdxf/7/

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
       <a href="#" class="slideshow-prev">prev</a> 
       <ul>
           <li><img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" alt="photo1" /><p>asdas</p></li>
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/4D99E0/ffffff.png&text=100x100" alt="photo2" /><p>ddd</p></li>
           <li><img src="http://www.matthijskamstra.nl/laboratory/flashbox/example_img/100x100pixels.gif" alt="photo3" /><p>eee</p></li>

       </ul>
        <a href="#" class="slideshow-next">next</a> 

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
}
ul{list-style:none;}
```

JQuery:

```
$('ul li').hide();
$('ul li:first').fadein();

var CurrentImage=0;
alert(CurrentImage);
var AllImage=$('#slideshow ul li').length;
alert(AllImage);
var NextImage=CurrentImage+1;

 $('.slideshow-next').click(function(){
      CurrentImage++;
     if(CurrentImage>=AllImages)
     {
         CurrentImage=0;
     }

 }
```

The code is incomplete and probably wrong.
I want to try to make a simple images and text SlideShow.

Unfortunately I did not do this and I'm stuck.
You can help me with an idea, how can I keep this example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could do `$('ul li').hide(); $('ul li').eq(CurrentImage).fadeIn();` at the end of the `onclick` listener

Comment: unforunately not working..

Comment: fix your errors before and : https://jsfiddle.net/4zuzxdxf/8/